# the common ratio of a geometric progression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

in a geometric progression each term is equal to the sum of the two preceding terms what can be said about the common ratio of this progression ?

I know this question relates the Fabonacci sequence and the golden ratio

fabonacci sequence 1,1,2,3,5,8,...

common ratio is (1+sqrt(5))/2 and (1-sqrt(5))/2

how do I start solving the qestion? should I start by the progression a1,a1,2a1,3a1,....
or a1,a2,a1+a2,a1+2a2,....?

[image: gelfand Algebra]

Comment: Strictly speaking, the Fibonacci series doesn't have a common ratio. The ratio only approaches the mentioned value ...

Comment: @Azam Caneene Say please, what do you want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

If the common ratio is $r$ then $a_{n+1}=ra_n$ and  $a_{n+2}=ra_{n+1}=r^2$

while $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n$ then implies $r^2 a_n = r a_n+a_n$

and if $a_n \not = 0$ then $r^2=r+1$ which gives the two possible common ratios you found

and you can then say $a_n=r^n a_0$. To go further you may need two early values of $a_n$

These $r$ represent the golden ratio, but the $a_n$ are not the Fibonacci sequence, which is not quite a geometric sequence but the sum of two geometric sequences using the two ratios

Answer (score 0):

You can start saying that $ a $ and $ b $ are the first terms of the geometric progression, and then build some more terms from these first two:

$$ a, b, a+b, a+2b, 2a+3b, ... $$

The common ratio of a geometric progression, $ q$, can be expressed as the ratio between any term and his preceding term. From the ones we built above:

$$ q = \dfrac{b}{a} = \dfrac{a+b}{b}  $$

Knowing that $ q = \dfrac{b}{a} $ can also be expressed as $ \dfrac{1}{q} = \dfrac{a}{b} $:

$$ q = \dfrac{a+b}{b} = \dfrac{a}{b} + \dfrac{b}{b} = \dfrac{a}{b} + 1 = \dfrac{1}{q} + 1   $$

So you have $ q = \dfrac{1}{q} + 1 $, multiply the equation by $ q $, to get $ q^2 = 1 + q $,  rearrange the terms in one side and you end up with a quadratic equation that when solved gives you the two common ratios from Gelfand, and one of those is the Golden ratio.